Estimator of θ using the method of moments ,using transformation g(θ)=ln x
Question:
We have a continuous random variable  with the probability density function (pdf):
$$_\theta(x) = \begin{cases}\theta/(x^\theta)+1, & x > 1,\theta > 0\\ 0,
&\textrm{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$
Find estimator of θ using the method of moment using transformation, $g(\theta) = \ln x$.
Approach:
Hi I am bit stuck with this problem, I tried using the general procedure at first which involves calculating the expectation of X, without taking the transformation to account,
$E(X)= \int_1^\infty xf_\theta(x)dx$
but could not find any solution.
I am posting this question here with hopes that someone might guide me on how to approach this problem. It would be really helpful if anyone could clarify if using the transformation could be the key to solution, and if that's the case, any insights on how to use that would be appreciated. Please don't downvote, I really need help.

Welcome to MSE, ARKA! Here is a brief tutorial on how to correctly format mathematical expressions with MathJax.

The density is presumably $\dfrac{\theta}{x^{\theta+1}}$ which is not what your brackets suggest.  If $\theta >1$ then the expectation is $1+\frac{1}{\theta-1}$ so a method of moment estimator of $\theta$ could be $1+\frac{1}{\frac1n\left(\sum x_i\right)-1}$.  But this does not answer the question since, before you do anything like that, you need to find the distribution  for $\log(X)$.

Actually I got this problem as a question during my bachelors semester exams, I had the same doubt which you suggested and presumed that might be the case. But no correction in question was suggested back then. So that actually kind of intrigues me to know if it is possible to solve somehow. Let's see if anyone provides any other insights.

@Henry 's correction to the density is essential.  From that you can find the cdf of $X$, followed by the cdf of $\log X$, and then the pdf and mean of $\log X$.

If the density is $\dfrac{\theta}{x^\theta}+1$ then you get $\infty$ when integrating over $x>1$.  If the density is $\dfrac{\theta}{x^\theta+1}$ then the integral is not easy but then unless $\theta \approx 3.761117795$ you do not get $1$ when integrating over $x>1$.   If the density is $\dfrac{\theta}{x^{\theta+1}}$ then  you do get $1$ when integrating over $x>1$.

yeah if the density is just what you guys are suggesting, then that makes things easier.
